# Are all humectants sticky?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, solvents, intermolecular-forces, viscosity, adhesion

While using a topical lotion based on [ethanol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethanol), water and [propylene glycol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propylene_glycol), I noticed that it becomes sticky while drying. Propylene glycol is a [humectant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humectant) and is used for this purpose in pharmaceuticals and cosmetics. This made me wonder: Is stickiness a general property of *all* humectants?

Comment: Hmm, humectants share 2 essential properties: 1/high hydrophilicity 2/ low volatility  // Both can be achieved e.g. by many hydrophilic groups like OH  ( glycols, glycerol, polyvinylalcohol PVA).  Not sure if PVA is sticky as well, but I would guess it may be. // It is quite possible stickiness and water retention are 2 aspects of the same quality here.// What may play role is the type of emultion ( oil in water or water in oil )